# Using REST client through a webpage

Tags: php, apache, rest, curl, elasticsearch

I want to get information from ElasticSearch on port 9200 in localhost via REST API and PHP. I have tried both cURL and REST client (HTTPFUL). When I run my PHP script in command line like this:

```
php searcher.php
php-cgi searcher.php
```

every thing works fine and get expected response. But when I do this through a web page, I get "Unable to connect " Error on REST client and nothing on cURL.
What is the problem?
By the way, I am using Apache on linux, manually configured besides PHP.
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to know with this little information, but my qualified guess would be it has something to do with firewall restrictions. (Port 80 for http-protocol)

Comment: I have checked firewall rules, too. But found nothing. What type of informatio do you need?

Comment: I think we need more on how you are doing this on a web page. Are you making the call directly from js to ES? are you hitting your local PHP? What does that code look like?

Comment: @Matt Wilson-spot on! :-)

Comment: ES are serving on the localhost too. I use a REST client to communicate directly with ES and get results.